# How to limit number of groups returned in a query, but not the number of rows in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

How to limit the number of groups in a query, but not the number of rows in Oracle?

If I had to do that manually, I would have to use a `DISTINCT`.

Would be something like this:

```
FOR d IN (
            SELECT DISTINCT COLUMN_1 FROM myTable
                WHERE myDate BETWEEN x AND y
                OFFSET o ROWS
                FETCH NEXT l ROWS ONLY
        ) LOOP
```

And then, do the selects from each of the ids returned in the query, which, in my opinion, is a terrible solution.

SAMPLE DATA:

[image]

If I limit the number of groups to 2 by using COLUMN_2, the expected result should be something like:

[image]

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help.

Comment: I don't understand. Are you looking to loop over all the rows from the base table (after the date filter), but only for a limited number of id's? (Note that your query doesn't have an ORDER BY clause, so the FETCH will be totally random - is that OK?)

Comment: Added sample data and desired result

Comment: You still didn't answer my question though. Do you care WHICH groups are selected? Or do you only care about HOW MANY?

Comment: Only how many groups are selected

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you may be looking for something like this:

```
select *
from   mytable
where  id in (
               select distinct id
               from   my_table
               where  my_date between x and y
               fetch  first :n rows only
             )
;
```

`:n` is a bind variable, encoding the number of groups you want to select.

This should be more efficient than solutions using analytic functions - even if it must read the base table twice. In tests posted on OTN, I showed that the difference is not small.

**EDIT** If I remember correctly, FETCH is not implemented in the most efficient way (perhaps for good reasons, having to do with features we don't need in this query - such as how to deal with ties). FETCH itself resembles a DENSE_RANK() implementation rather than the faster row limiting clause (using ROWNUM). I would likely need to modify the query to do away with FETCH, if speed was really important. **END EDIT**

**Further edit** to do with performance comparisons

Frequent poster **MT0** requested a pointer for the claim that aggregate solutions can (and often are) more efficient than analytic function approaches, even when the former may require multiple passes through the data where the analytic function approach requires only one.

Alas, OTN (what now calls itself the "Oracle Groundbreakers Developer Community", the discussion board hosted by Oracle itself) went through a massive - and massively botched - platform change at the end of September 2020; that messed up both the search facilities and the formatting of old posts, to the point of rendering them almost unusable.

Instead, I will show here a simple mock-up of the OP's problem in this thread; code that anyone can run so they can repeat the tests on their own machine.

I created a table with two columns, ID and STR - the ID plays the same role as in the OP's question, and STR is just extra payload to mimic real-life data. ID is number and STR is varchar2(100). I populated the table with 9 million rows - 1 million ID's, nine rows for each ID. The task is to select just three "groups" (three distinct ID's, then select all the rows from the base table for those three distinct ID's).

With no index on the ID column, the aggregate solution runs in 0.81 seconds on my machine; with an index on ID, it runs in 0.47 seconds. The analytic functions solution runs in 0.91 seconds, with or without an index (obviously - there is no way an index can benefit the analytic function solution). All these results are for column ID not declared NOT NULL.

Here is the code to create the table, the index on ID, and the two queries I tested. ***Note***: As I explained in my first edit (above), `fetch` is slow; I replaced it with a standard row-limiting technique using `ROWNUM` in an over-query.

```
drop table t purge;

create table t (id number, str varchar2(100));

insert into t
  with    row_gen as (select level from dual connect by level <= 3000)
  select  mod(344227 * rownum, 1000000), rpad('x', 100, 'x')
  from    row_gen cross join row_gen
;

commit;

create index t_idx on t(id);

select *
from   t
where  id in (
  select id from (select distinct id from t)
  where  rownum <= 3
);

select *
from   ( select t.*, dense_rank() over (order by id) dr from t )
where  dr <= 3;
```

Comment: "In tests posted on OTN, I showed that the difference is not small." Please can we have a citation for this claim.

Comment: @MT0 - alas, OTN switched platforms, and now it is very difficult to search older threads (I just tried, and I couldn't find the relevant posts quickly). Worse, even if you can find them, the formatting of old threads (meaning, before October 2020) is all messed up, so the posts are almost impossible to read. You can, though, find some of my comments elsewhere - on Jonathan Lewis's blog, for example the second comment here: https://jonathanlewis.wordpress.com/2020/03/12/dense_rank/ Jonathan's post has all the code needed to set up the tests.

Comment: @MT0 - although... if I remember correctly, FETCH itself turns out to be implemented similar to an analytic DENSE_RANK instead of a simple ROWNUM limit; so I may have to re-write my query using ROWNUM if it must be fast. I will edit my post to clarify at least that point.

Comment: I guess there's no really "performer" way to do this kind of thing, since DISTINCT always cause the queries to be slow... I mean, the solution is working nice, but, if I need to return something like 1000 groups, depending on the use case, this would be a big bottleneck. My use case is a restful API to return all of these groups so the performance could be a problem. Event using ROWNUM to limit results, I don't see the performance being dramatically increased. Anyway, this solves the problem. Thank you!

Comment: @MatheusCirillo - there **should** be a performant way to do this, since the "distinct" shouldn't be processed for all the inputs. As soon as at least "n" distinct "groups" have been recognized, that part of the query should stop executing and pass control back to the environment. Whether there's a way to do that in Oracle SQL, I am not sure. I'll do some tests (using ROWNUM instead of FETCH) to see how it goes; I'll do it when I have a bit of time.

Comment: @MT0 - I edited my answer (above) to add a timed test of the two approaches on a problem mimicking the OP's setup.

Comment: @MatheusCirillo - I edited my post further; in the aggregate solution, you can see how I used a row-limiting condition using `ROWNUM` instead of `FETCH`. If performance is critical, you may want to try something similar on your real-life data. Also note the improvement from having an index on the `id` column.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `DENSE_RANK`:

```
SELECT *
FROM   (
  SELECT t.*,
         DENSE_RANK() OVER ( ORDER BY column2 ) AS rnk
  FROM   table_name t
)
WHERE  rnk <= 2;
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name ( column1, column2, column3, column4 ) AS
SELECT 1, 1, 1.0, 1.0 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 2, 2.0, 2.0 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 2, 2.2, 2.1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 2, 2.2, 2.2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 2, 2.0, 2.3 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 3, 3.0, 3.1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 3, 3.1, 3.1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 3, 3.1, 3.1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 4, 4, 4.2, 4.0 FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> ```
> COLUMN1 | COLUMN2 | COLUMN3 | COLUMN4 | RNK
> ------: | ------: | ------: | ------: | --:
>       1 |       1 |       1 |       1 |   1
>       2 |       2 |       2 |       2 |   2
>       2 |       2 |     2.2 |     2.1 |   2
>       2 |       2 |     2.2 |     2.2 |   2
>       2 |       2 |       2 |     2.3 |   2
> ```

*(and, if you want `DISTINCT` rows then add `DISTINCT` to the outer query)*

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=facee6e82e924965c1acf9a2e79e3271)*

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want `ROW_NUMBER()`:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM (SELECT t.*,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY id) as seqnum
      FROM myTable t
      WHERE t.myDate BETWEEN x AND y
      ) t
WHERE seqnum = 1;
```

This returns an arbitrary row for each `id` meeting the conditions.

Comment: What is *ever* the point of ordering by the same expression as you partition by, in an analytic function?

Comment: Added sample data + desired result in the question

Comment: @mathguy . . . Some databases require the `order by` so I use that as a default.  It works across all databases.

Comment: Yes, but the "normal" way to do that is to write `order by null`, or if you don't like that, order by some hardcoded literal (`order by 0` or `order by 'x'`). Having `order by id` will confuse the reader - especially a reader who is not too familiar with analytic functions.

Comment: @mathguy . . . Those alas are not supported by SQL Server.